# Reverse a string without using string functions

Tags: java

How to write a java program to reverse a string without using string functions?

```
 String a="Siva";

 for(int i=0;i<=a.length()-1;i++)
 {
     System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
 }
     System.out.println("");

 for(int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
 {
     System.out.print(a.charAt(i)); 
 }
```

here `charAt()` and `a.length()` are string functions

Comment: Do you want to reverse the string itself or just print it reversed?

Comment: just print it reversed

Comment: Without using *any* methods, you simply can't get at the data. Presumably this is homework, so I suggest you ask your tutor which methods you *are* allowed to use.

Comment: Without using any String methods we cant reverse a a string?

Comment: Refer http://learnjava-soa.blogspot.in/2016/02/write-java-program-without-using.html

Answer (score 7):

This will help

```
public class StringReverse {

   public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "Reverse";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    str = sb.reverse().toString();
    System.out.println("ReverseString : "+str);
  }

}
```

There is no usage of String methods

Comment: str.toCharArray() is a string function

Comment: Pff, i went till.
  String str = "test";
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("$").matcher(str);
  m.find();
  int length = m.end();

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "abcdef";
char c[] = s.toCharArray();

for( int i = c.length -1; i>=0; i--)
    System.out.print(c[i]);
```

Comment: length() is string function

Comment: It is length not length()

Comment: `toCharArray()` string functions.

Comment: s.toCharArray() array is a string function

Comment: Considering Java I think we cannot accomplish reverse without using functions since it does not support pointers directly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `StringBuilder` class or `StringBuffer` class they have already a method `reverse()` for reversing  the string

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("india");
System.out.println("string = " + str);

// reverse characters of the StringBuilder and prints it
System.out.println("reverse = " + str.reverse());

// reverse is equivalent to the actual
str = new StringBuilder("malayalam");
System.out.println("string = " + str);

// reverse characters of the StringBuilder and prints it
System.out.println("reverse = " + str.reverse());
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 1):

Below is ugly hack. It concept but it not invoke any `String` methods.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Hello {
    public static String reverceWithoutStringMethods(String word){
        String result = "";
        //------ Write string to file -----------
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("tempfile"));
            writer.write(word);
        }
        catch ( IOException e) {}
        finally {
            try{
                if ( writer != null) writer.close( );
            }
            catch ( IOException e){}
        }
        //------ read string from file -------------
        RandomAccessFile f=null;
        try {
             f = new RandomAccessFile("tempfile", "r"); // Open file
            int length = (int) f.length(); // Get length
            // Read file
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            f.readFully(data);
            // Reverse data
            for (int i=data.length; i>=0; i--){
                result += (char)data[i-1];
            }
        } catch(Exception e){}
        finally {
            try{
                f.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println(reverceWithoutStringMethods("Test"));
        System.out.println(reverceWithoutStringMethods(""));
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
tseT
```

Comment: charAt() word.length() are string functions

Comment: @JeevanRoydsouza see update.It not invoke any String method.

Comment: Yup we can do like this also.